Ansible playbook to format and mount unused disks
I am trying to setup a disk on Linux with Ansible. I am fairly new to ansible.
I have managed to get a list of all unused disks (though it will probably consist of just one) but I am having issues to format and mount it.
I get the device info on a dictionry but I can manage to get the actual evice path (/dev/sdb for example):
---
- name: Prepare unformatted disk
  hosts: test_hosts
  gather_facts: true
  remote_user: confmanager
  become: true
  tasks:

      - name: Get unformatted disks
        ansible.builtin.set_fact:
            disks: "{{ disks | default([]) + ['/dev/' + item.key] }}"
        when:
            - not item.value.partitions
            - item.key | regex_search ("sd")
        with_dict: "{{ ansible_devices }}"

      - name: Show unformatted disks
        ansible.builtin.debug:
            msg: "{{ disks }}"

      - name: Format disk
        community.general.filesystem:
            fstype: btrfs
            device: "{{ disks }}"

      - name: Mount disk
        ansible.posix.mount:
            state: mounted
            fstype: btrfs
            path: /storage
            src: "{{ disks + '1' }}"

And the error:
TASK [Format disk] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [testserver]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Device ['/dev/sdb'] not found."}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
testserver

I think I really don't get how to extract the "/dev/sdb" part from each disk.
Also it would be nice to know how to loop over all unformatted disks.

The disks fact is a list, and I see no indication in the documentation that the Ansible filesystem module accepts a list for the device parameter. Have you tried using a loop on the Format disk task? Better yet, put all of the tasks (except Get unformatted disks) in a separate file, then use include_tasks in that remaining task to include that file, which then loops over each entry

Be careful with your check. Just because a disk does not have partitions it does not mean it's not in use. They might be used in a RAID, LVM, Ceph or similar.

Even your playbook will reformat them on subsequent runs because it does not create partitions.

There is no reliable way to determine that disk is not in use in Linux. One case I can easily imagine is when it is in use, but not in a continuous use and isn't used right now, and it's use doesn't imply there are recognizable structures. For example, bytes 4096÷4128 may contain (part of) encryption key, and only used during system boot. Or it can hold an encrypted backup of a system (tar dump).

@jpiddle888 you are right, how can I loop through the itemson the list? this way?: - name: Format disks
community.general.filesystem:
fstype: btrfs
device: "{{ item }}"
loop: "{{ disks }}"

@NikitaKipriyanov and gerald, this is a quite specific scenario, the machines are cloud init templates and no other disk was added except the boot one. So essentially 100% of the unused disks are just new disks. So no risk there.

@javiers comments like that are not only for you, but also for people who find this question later and think it is a good idea to use it for their use case, which might not be so specific. And my second comment still applies to your case. You should create partitions before formatting and mounting if you intend to run the playbook more than once per VM.

@javiers Yes, you would loop through that way, but you'd need to do it for the Mount disk option as well. When you get to running multiple tasks with the same loop, it becomes cleaner to use include_tasks to apply the loop to multiple tasks at once. Also, heed Gerald's warning about partitions. As is, the Mount disk task will not work, as mkfs doesn't create partitions; it creates a filesystem directly on the device. However, it won't overwrite a formatted device unless you use the force parameter.
